# In setInterval() a block of code should run once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running a block of code with the interval of 1 sec which is fine. But I am having an issue that the callback function `check_live_records()` has an AJAX call and in its `success` I want to run a block of code just once which I am unable to execute. What can be the possible way to achieve this?

The expectation is that the following code only adds a single row once if there is a new record.

`// update bidding table` block should run once for each change

```js
var running = false;
var _interval = 1;

if (_interval) {
  setInterval(function() {
    check_live_records();
  }, _interval * 1000);
}

function check_live_records() {
  if (typeof running === 'boolean' && running === true) {
    return;
  }

  running = true;

  var displayRow = 0; // i tried adding a varibale to control this 

  $.ajax({
      url: ajaxUrl,
      type: 'POST',
      encoding: 'UTF-8',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: {
        action: 'get_live_records',
        last_timestamp: last_timestamp
      },
      success: function(response) {
        if (response != null) {
          $.each(response.auctions, function(key, value) {
              if (key > 0) {
                var tableRow = $('tr#auction-' + key);
                if (tableRow.length) {
                  // change current price value
                  tableRow.find('.column-current_price').html(value.wua_curent_bid);

                  if (value.table_row) {
                    if (displayRow == 0) {
                      // update bidding table
                      var logs = value.table_row;
                      console.log(displayRow);
                      var _row = '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' + logs.user_display_name + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + logs.currency_symbol + logs.current_bid + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + logs.currency_symbol + logs.max_bid + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + logs.date + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>';
                      tableRow.find('table#auction_bidding_table_' + key + ' tbody').prepend(_row);
                      displayRow + 1;
                    }
                  }
                }
              });
          }
          running = false;
        },
        error: function() {
          running = false;
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Aside from the issue, the code in the question has some syntax issues from missing parentheses/braces. Also note that making an AJAX request every 1 second to your server is not a good idea. It does not scale, and you will quickly DDOS yourself with a small number of concurrent users.

Comment: so what suggestions do you have, actually I have to check if I have any updates, there are several users adding data to the same table and on each entry, data should be shown updated. that's why I setup setInterval()

Comment: If you need to keep the UI in close sync with the server state, use the [observer pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer). In my experience, websockets is perfect for this.

Comment: I'm not very good with javascript

Comment: `web socket` is better and recommended approach for this kind of real time data apps.

Comment: its WordPress project with native javascript and jquery